# Validate the current row of a column, if zero give the previous row's value or else provide the current row's value

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I am trying to create a calculated column which checks each row of the column `[scenario repay option test]`, if = 0 then provide the last rows value or else provide the current value.

However I am not able to get the values correctly repeated.
[result after the formula below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhQvm.jpg)

[image]

```
If(Sum([Scenario repay option test]) OVER(Next([RowID]))=0,Sum([Scenario repay option test])OVER (All([RowID])),[Scenario repay option test])
```

Could you please advise what am i missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Shaktiraj jena- Here are the steps to accomplish this.

**Step 1:** Modify `row_id` expression. `row_id` will be null if the value of `[Original col]` is 0.

```
If([Original col]<>0,RowId(),null)
```

**Step 2:** Add a calculated column which finds the previous value of `scenario repay option test` column

```
Sum([scenario repay option test]) over (Previous([row_id]))
```

*Note: This column runs in the background. Need not display it in the table.*

**Step 3:** Finally, add a calculated column which checks your condition.

```
If([scenario repay option test]=0,[previous_value],[scenario repay option test])
```

**Sample output:**

[image]

Comment: Good answer ksp

Comment: Thank you scsimon.